PhpUnit error Class Qameta\Allure\PHPUnit\AllureExtension does not have a constructor, so you cannot pass any constructor arguments
I am getting the below error while running PHPUnit command in Magento 2
Class Qameta\Allure\PHPUnit\AllureExtension does not have a constructor, so you cannot pass any constructor arguments

How to fix this?

To fix this issue use below solution
goto file dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist and remove below code
<extensions>
    <extension class="Qameta\Allure\PHPUnit\AllureExtension">
        <!-- Optional arguments block; omit it if you want to use default values -->
        <arguments>
            <!-- Path to config file (default is config/allure.config.php) -->
            <string>allure/allure.config.php</string>
        </arguments>
    </extension>
</extensions>

This will fix the above issue
Hope this will help,
Thank You!
